# Data not rendering in plot

Tags: r

I'm new to R and doing a homework. We need to make an example on a given data set for random forest and feature interaction. When I run the code I get the plot but without any data. Please help me because I never programmed in R and I need to do this. Thank you!

I already tried to use just the columns without N/A values

```
  X <- student_data_train %>%
    select(-GradePASS) %>%
    as.data.frame()

  predictor <- Predictor$new(rf_model, data = X, y = student_data_train$GradePASS)
  str(predictor)

  install.packages("devtools")
  library(devtools)
  interact <- Interaction$new(predictor, feature = "selfassesm")
  interact$plot()
  interact$results %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(.feature, .interaction), y = .interaction, fill = .class)) +
    facet_wrap(~ .class, ncol = 2) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.8) +
    scale_fill_tableau() +
    coord_flip() +
    guides(fill = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please try to make your code a **minimal** and **reproducible** example... Typically, if your issue is with the last plot, then 90% of your code is not relevant, just give us a sample of `interact$results` and keep only the code for the plot.

Comment: Hi, sorry I edited my code now.

Comment: I am getting this error message:
Error in private$interaction.run.single(dataSample = data.sample, feature.name = c(feature,  : 
  task 1 failed - "Assertion on 'all(features %in% colnames(grid.dat))' failed: Must be TRUE."